# Why am I getting a `generic error in gdi+` exception using `Image.SelectActiveFrame`?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, tiff

I'm developing a `C# (WinForms)` program using `.NET Framework 4.7.2`, where I input a `TIF/TIFF` file, which **can** have multiple pages (or frames if that's the correct term), then load each image (frame) to new `Bitmap` objects, allowing me to show the images to a PictureBox.

I have multiple TIFF files, and all of them seem to be okay. I input them through my program, and then they generate one Bitmap for every page (frame) they have and they look fine as if I have opened the TIFF files in a regular Windows image viewer (For example, IrfanView).

There's one TIFF file that simply will not work with my program. It opens fine with IrfanView and I'm able to scroll through its pages (frames) and view its images properly. I don't know what the issue is. If the file was faulty, then IrfanView or any other image viewer that supports TIFFs would report something? I am guessing that I am missing something in my code.

```
using (Image imageFile = Image.FromFile("MyImage.tif"))
{
    FrameDimension frameDimensions = new FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

    // Gets the number of pages from the tiff image (if multipage) 
    int frameNum = imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions);

    for (int frame = 0; frame < frameNum; frame++)
    {
        // Selects one frame at a time and save as jpeg. 
        imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, frame); // This throws the exception

        // Work with imageFile, show in PictureBox for example.
    }
}
```

The 'faulty' TIFF file seems to return the correct number of frames through `GetFrameCount`, and no exception message is seen being printed in the Output window. The `SelectActiveFrame` throws the `Generic error in GDI+` when `frame` is above zero. The first frame passes, but the second one and the rest throw the error. I have also confirmed this without using for loop and simply putting the indexes myself. The frame looks okay, but I can't load the rest from that TIFF file!

Hundreds of threads with the same question, and no clear answer, suggest that `imageFile` in this example is being Disposed before `GetFrameCount` is being called. I have confirmed this to be false by implementing `using` for the `Image` object, or simply using `imageFile.Dispose()` after the frame loop. Or am I missing something?

I am unable to share the TIFF files, neither does the project manager know whether they have been through a different encoding process, or anything that makes it different from the rest, leaving the mystery behind it unknown, but I'm definitely curious as to why the error may occur and how to fix this. Surely, IrfanView would go haywire and show me nothing in the TIFF file if the file was corrupted or damaged.

---

Reference: IrfanView 4.62

One of the frames in the TIFF that works:

[image: Working frame]

One of the frames in the TIFF that doesn't work.

[image: Faulty frame]

Comment: It is a "generic error", could be anything.  First candidate with code like this is running out of available address space (aka "out of memory"), target 64-bit code with Project > Properties > Build tab and try again.

Comment: What is the format f that TIFF? What is its size and the size of each frame? -- If the format is 16bit gray scale, you have to use System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Comment: @Jimi The frames vary either `1BPP` or `24BPP`, and the dimensions vary as well from 1920x1080, to 4000x3000, and inbetween. Same goes for the other TIFFs that load fine.

Comment: @HansPassant That didn't do anything. There's a non-faulty TIFF that has well over 89 frames and they load well. The faulty one has 17 frames, has similar dimensions/bits per pixel variations as the non-faulty ones, but this error gets thrown. Funnily enough, the faulty one is amongst the smaller files in bytes per frame. :^)

Comment: There are TIFF validators, I suggest you run that file through some. Just because one program loads the image doesn’t mean it’s valid.

Comment: Besides the number of bits, what color space? As mentioned, if the image is 16 or 24 or whatever Gray Scale, those formats are not supported. CCITT Group 4 is supported. Not all compression methods are supported

Comment: @Jimi I've updated my question and added two references to one of the frames of each TIFF. One that works, and of the one that doesn't.

Comment: "old style jpeg".  TIFF = Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.

Comment: If you can change the compression method (it's not something your app needs to explicitly support), then do that. Otherwise, as mentioned, try first with `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` . If it doesn't handle it (probable), then you could test [Magik.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET), many more formats supported (still, not all)

Comment: TIFF is not really an image format, it is a container format that can hold images of several different formats. It's likely your offending file does not load, it's likely your code does not support the image format. Most of my TIFF experience comes from manipulating Fax images (CCITT group 3) - it was a while back. If we'd get an image of the wrong type, we'd just signal an error

Comment: `Magick.NET` did the trick, for now... Just waiting for my pm to find an even older and rarer format :^)

Haven't tried `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`, nor don't know how to implement to my code, but I'm gonna stick with the library for now. Thanks to everyone for helping and useful info.